# PHP/WordPress - Register every array element for translation?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

usually I register an element for translation when using this function:

```
__('String','textdomain');
```

Now I have an array from the database with the following contents:

**$tour_languages:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "english"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "german"
}
```

Now I want to achieve that "english" and "german" are registered for translation. Can I do this without using a foreach? I tried it with this, but it does not work as expected, because I do not have the single item available.

```
echo implode(', ', __($tour_languages, 'textdomain'));
```

Has someone an idea or do I need to use foreach?
Thanks!

Comment: whats wrong with using foreach?